# Core Graphics with DisplayLink Unexpected Behavior

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I'm trying to learn Core Graphics and am having trouble understanding the behavior of the code I've written, which uses a subclassed UIView and an override of the `draw(_ rect:)` function.

I've written a basic bouncing ball demo. Any number of random balls are created with random position and speed. They then bounce around the screen.

My issue is the way that the balls appear to move is unexpected and there is a lot of flicker. Here is the sequence inside for loops to iterate through all balls:

1. Check for collisions.
2. If there is a collision with the wall, multiply speed by -1.
3. Increment ball position by ball speed.

I'm currently not clearing the context, so I would expect the existing balls to stay put. Instead they seem to slide smoothly along with the ball that's moving.
I'd like to understand why this is the case.

Here is an image of how the current code runs at 4 fps so that you can see how the shapes are being drawn and shift back and forth:

[image: screen grab of an iOS application with 5 balls being rendered randomly on screen with random velocities and positions.]

Here is my code:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let myView = MyView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(myView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor)
        ])
        
        createDisplayLink(fps: 60)
    }
    
    func createDisplayLink(fps: Int) {
        let displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self,
                                        selector: #selector(step))
        
        displaylink.preferredFramesPerSecond = fps
        
        displaylink.add(to: .current,
                        forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    }
    
    @objc func step(displaylink: CADisplayLink) {
        myView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

class MyView: UIView {
    
    let numBalls = 5
    var balls = [Ball]()
    
    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        
        for _ in 0..<numBalls {
            balls.append(
                Ball(
                    ballPosition: Vec2(x: CGFloat.random(in: 0...UIScreen.main.bounds.width), y: CGFloat.random(in: 0...UIScreen.main.bounds.height)),
                    ballSpeed: Vec2(x: CGFloat.random(in: 0.5...2), y: CGFloat.random(in: 0.5...2))))
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        for i in 0..<numBalls {
            if balls[i].ballPosition.x > self.bounds.width - balls[i].ballSize || balls[i].ballPosition.x < 0 {
                balls[i].ballSpeed.x *= -1
            }
            
            balls[i].ballPosition.x += balls[i].ballSpeed.x
            
            if balls[i].ballPosition.y > self.bounds.height - balls[i].ballSize || balls[i].ballPosition.y < 0 {
                balls[i].ballSpeed.y *= -1
                
            }
            balls[i].ballPosition.y += balls[i].ballSpeed.y
        }
        
        for i in 0..<numBalls {
            context.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
            context.setLineWidth(0)
            
            let rectangle = CGRect(x: balls[i].ballPosition.x, y: balls[i].ballPosition.y, width: balls[i].ballSize, height: balls[i].ballSize)
            context.addEllipse(in: rectangle)
            context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UIKit dynamics or SpriteKit would be a better tool.

Comment: I understand. I'm working on a framework that will put the responsibility of managing graphics in the programmer's hands. It's for educational purposes. I need my users to control clearing the screen and animation themselves imperatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of misunderstandings here, so I'll try to take them one by one:

- CADisplayLink does not promise it will call your step method every 1/60 of a second. There's a reason the property is called **preferred** frames per second. It's just a hint to the system of what you'd like. It may call you less often, and in any case there will be some amount of error.
- To perform your own animations by hand, you need to look at what time is actually attached to the given frame, and use that to determine where things are. The CADisplayLink includes a `timestamp` to let you know that. You can't just increment by speed. You need to multiply speed by actual time to determine distance.
- "I'm currently not clearing the context, so I would expect the existing balls to stay put." Every time `draw(rect:)` is called, you receive a fresh context. It is your responsibility to draw everything for the current frame. There is no persistence between frames. (Core Animation generally provides those kinds of features by efficiently composing CALayers together; but you've chosen to use Core Graphics, and there you need to draw everything every time. We generally do not use Core Graphics this way.)
- `myView.setNeedsDisplay()` does not mean "draw this frame right now." It means "the next time you're going to draw, this view needs to be redrawn." Depending on exactly when the CADisplayLink fires, you may drop a frame, or you might not. Using Core Graphics, you would need to update all the circle's locations before calling `setNeedsDisplay()`. Then `draw(rect:)` should just draw them, not compute what they are. (CADisplayLink is really designed to work with CALayers, though, and NSView drawing isn't designed to be updated so often, so this still may be a little tricky to keep smooth.)

The more normal way to create this system would be to generate a CAShapeLayer for each ball and position them on the NSView's layer. Then in the CADisplayLink callback, you would adjust their positions based on the timestamp of the next frame. Alternately, you could just set up a repeating NSTimer or DispatchTimerSource (rather than a CADisplayLink) at something well below the screen refresh speed (like 1/20 s) and move the layer positions in that callback. This would be nice and simple and avoid the complexities of CADisplayLink (which is much more powerful, but expects you to use the timestamp and consider other soft real-time concerns).

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. Your response now makes me even more confused about the persistence I'm experiencing (updated post with image). If draw provides a fresh context every time it is called, I have no idea why every previous ball seems to still be drawing. I don't actually mind that the 60 fps is preferred and not exact. I think that's Ok and I don't need the animations to be exact in terms of timing like Core Animation might provide.

Comment: You're not clearing the view first. What you're given isn't promised to be initialized memory (that would waste time when you were drawing everything anyway). Typically you'd do something like `NSColor.black.set; NSBezierPath.fill(rect)`. (That just fills the "dirty" rectangle, which is the only part you absolutely have to draw. You could fill your bounds instead.)

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. I just added `self.backgroundColor = .black` to the beginning of ` I'm still curious what's going on under the hood that would make the previously drawn shapes shift back and forth the way they are if it's just me not clearing the context by setting the backgroundColor property of the view. In my mental model of the way it works, those previously drawn circles should stay put. Do you know why they shift like that?

Comment: Core Graphics objects are recycled whenever possible. So I would not be surprised to receive back a CGContext that I'd just drawn into a couple of frames ago (maybe even three frames). Whatever the cycle is, it's likely to repeat, so if there are two contexts, you'd draw every even frame into one and every odd into another. Given your overlap, you'd see that as shifting back and forth (because of where the first circle gets drawn). You'd see the same behavior for a three frame cycle.

Comment: I wouldn't particularly expect to see the context I just used come back on the next frame, though (given the speed at which you're doing this). It probably wouldn't make it into the recycle pile before you asked for another context. If you were drawing much more slowly, then that might be more possible, and give you the illusion that a CGContext is a persistent canvas. (I'm blurring the meaning of "CGContext" here and "the internal backing store the context draws into." But they're very different things, so don't confuse them.)

Comment: I highly encourage you to study Core Animation, however, and specifically CALayer. I believe it will make a better foundation for this educational tool. Layers behave a bit more like your mental model (not completely; they're still complicated and have many subtitles, but closer). You can still do all the animations completely by hand using layers and draw with CoreGraphics.

Comment: You're doing really well here, digging into all the bits and pieces. I expect you'll come away with a pretty solid understanding of the system by the time you're done. To learn more Core Graphics, I recommend https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066 and for Core Animation https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: (I so wish Apple still wrote Programming Guides, or updated the old ones. They were the best docs I've ever dealt with. It's very hard to find a comprehensive "here's how this technology works" document for anything Apple has released in years.)